# vue-i18n throwing error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')"

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am using a basic routing taken from the vue.js page and I cannot make vue-i18n run together with it.

My code in the main.js currently looks like this (my latest try):

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import routes from './routes'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import de from './locale/de';
import en from './locale/en';
/* import App from './App.vue' */

const SimpleRouter = {
    data: () => ({
        currentRoute: window.location.pathname
    }),

    computed: {
      ViewComponent () {
        const matchingPage = routes[this.currentRoute] || '404'
        return require(`./pages/${matchingPage}.vue`).default
      }
    },
  
    render () {
      return h(this.ViewComponent)
    },
  
    created () {
      window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
        this.currentRoute = window.location.pathname
      })
    }
}

var app = createApp(SimpleRouter)
app.use(VueI18n,{
  locale: 'de',
  messages: {
      de,
      en
  },
)
app.mount('#app')
```

but I get an error stating "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')"

EDIT: The error Message from chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
    at extend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm.js:225)
    at Function.install (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm.js:752)
    at Object.use (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3226)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:62)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:3687)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:3999)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
```

EDIT end.

I also tried to put the i18n stuff into another file, but I could not make the file use it - honestly I didn't know where to put it.
This did not work:
`var app = createApp({SimpleRouter, i18n})`
nor did adding it to the `SimpleRouter` definition like this:

````
   i18n,
    data: () => ({
..```
````

Comment: I tried this from the vue.js page (making an own 'i18n' plugin) and here it works.
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#using-a-plugin

There I can include the plugin and just use it by calling 
`app.use(i18nPlugin, i18nStrings)`

Comment: If there is any context for the error message, such as a source file + line number, that would help.

Comment: @Appurist-PaulW I added chrome's error message to the question.